# Adding parameters into URL via django url name

Tags: python, django, url, namespaces

There are following files:

```
#urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'some_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('some_url/', views.view_func, name='some_url')
]
```

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import redirect


def index(request):
    return redirect('some_app:some_url')


def view_func(request):
    pass
```

Now, if I follow the first link (index) it will redirect me to `/some_url/`.
How can I change my code to add any parameters to URL for redirecting to `/some_url/?param1=abc&param2=def`?

Comment: From where you will get <param1=abc&param2=def> these values? you want to send them as query string params right?

Answer (score 0):

For ex. id param. u can set url like this;

url;

```
url(r'^testurl/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.testurl, name='testurl'),
```

view;

```
 def testurl(request,id):
```